# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds

Tags: php, mysql

При поиске выводит сообщение об ошибке:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''name_colors' WHERE secret=0 AND MATCH(HSV) AGAINST('100')' at line 1

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","php","12345");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'cp1251'");
mysql_select_db("color",$db);

if (isset($_POST['submit_s']))
{
$submit_s = $_POST['submit_s'];
}

if (isset($_POST['search']))
{
$search = $_POST['search'];
}

if (isset($submit_s))
{

if (empty($search) or strlen($search) < 1)
{
exit ("<p>Поисковый запрос не введен, либо он менее 1 символа.</p>");
}

$search = trim($search);
$search = stripslashes($search);
$search = htmlspecialchars($search);

}

else 
{
exit("<p>Вы обратились к файлу без необходимых параметров.</p>");
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT name_colors, HEX, HSV, CMYK  FROM 'name_colors' WHERE secret=0 AND MATCH(HSV) AGAINST('$search')",$db);
if (!$result)
{
echo "<p>Запрос на выборку данных из базы не прошел. Напишите об этом администратору. <br> <strong>Код ошибки:</strong></p>";
exit(mysql_error());
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)

{
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result); 

echo"<table align='center'> <tr><th>Название цвета</th>
    <th>HEX</th>
    <th>HSV</th>
    <th>CMYK</th></tr>";
do {
printf ("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $myrow["name_colors"], $myrow["HEX"], $myrow["HSV"], $myrow["CMYK"]);
}
while($myrow =  mysql_fetch_array($result));

echo"</table>";
}

?>
<p><div class="">Поиск</div>
        <form action="view_search.php" method="post" name="form_s">

        <p><input name="search" type="text" size="25" maxlength="40">
        <br><input name="submit_s" type="submit" value="Искать">
        </p>
        </form>

        </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Структура**:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Покажите структуру таблицы.

Comment: KoVadim, вот структура:http://i63.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0529/47/74f88d736a42337bee2b4e0564696447.png

Answer (score 1):

Кавычки

```
'name_colors'
```

замените на обратные

```
`name_colors`
```

или вообще их уберите.

Answer (score 0):

А что это у Вас в условии запроса за **secret=0** в таблице такого поля нет, вот скорее всего отсюда и ошибка.

*Обновление*

Проверьте что на входе в скрипт выдает $_POST['search']

Ппопробуйте вывести в браузере всю строку запроса, потом опробовать этот запрос в каком-то из менеджеров БД.

И еще попробуйте сделать так:

```
result = mysql_query("SELECT name_colors, HEX, HSV, CMYK  FROM 'name_colors' WHERE secret=0 AND MATCH(HSV) AGAINST('".$search."')",$db);
```

Comment: Убрал и все равно  выдает эту ошибку

Comment: Все равно ошибку выводит эту ошибку, а если убрать "if", то выдает Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\prak\SITE_PHP\view_search.php on line 71  
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\prak\SITE_PHP\view_search.php on line 88 
У меня не хотело принимать в БД тип FULLTEXT и поэтому я через запрос сделал это принудительно, может из-за этого?

Comment: Проверьте какой тип БД использует, если MyISAM то вроде как могут быть проблемы... попробуйте использовать InnoDB.

Comment: Изменил тип - не помогло. Выдает Notice: Undefined variable: search in C:\apache\test.ru\www\view_search.php on line 37

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\apache\test.ru\www\view_search.php on line 40

name_colors  HEX  HSV  RGB   

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\apache\test.ru\www\view_search.php on line 61

$result = mysql_query("SELECT name_colors,HEX,HSV,CMYK  FROM 'code_color' WHERE  MATCH(HSV) AGAINST('$search')",$db);

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо! Уже работает поиск)